# Cannot add a hook after tests have started running. Hooks must be defined synchronously

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

My current test fails.

**Test code**

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { HealthController } from './health.controller';

describe('HealthController', () => {
  let controller: HealthController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [HealthController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<HealthController>(HealthController);
  });

  describe('check', () => {
    it('should return status 200', () => {
      expect(controller.check()).toBe('success');
    });
  });
});
```

**error**

> Cannot add a hook after tests have started running. Hooks must be defined synchronously.

```
   5 |   let controller: HealthController;
   6 |
>  7 |   beforeEach(async () => {
     |   ^
   8 |     const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
   9 |       controllers: [HealthController],
  10 |     }).compile();
```

Comment: what version of Jest do you use?

Comment: @Marek Urbanowicz I'm using version 27.

Comment: Found this discussion around async jest lifecycles: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1256
Try using a done callback with async. 
async (done) => { //await your stuff 
done(); }
It worked out for some folks. But issue would be that errors wouldn't be propagated.

Comment: @alchemist95 thanks, I’m gonna try it.

Comment: it didin't work :(

Comment: please create repro repo. I will try to help you